# Button disappears after clicking in HTML page

Tags: html

I have `index.html` page with start button when I click on start button button disappears and other background remains same until new page opens how to make the button visible after click until moved to next page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="splashcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
     <body>
         <div id="container">
         <div id="image"><a href="overview.html">
             <img src="image/startbutton.png" onmouseover="this.src='image/Startbuttonmouse.png'" onmouseout="this.src='image/startbutton.png'"> 
         </div> 
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not closing the elements properly... add `</a></div>` after `<img />` tag.

Comment: and again doing this button disappears how to solve this issue

Comment: what do you mean by "mask a url"? any example?

Comment: I've tried your code in Chrome, FF and IE, but I can't see the problem you described... have you done anything to the element in your css?

Comment: @mean i haver web address google.com/brd/index.html and so on pages i want to display on url bar only google.com/brd only not the pages on which i am

Comment: you may want to "rewrite url"